# Finding defective balls from a set of n balls

Tags: algorithm

Similar to the defective ball problem, you are given n balls, however with an unknown number of defective balls and good balls. There is at least 1 good ball and at least 1 defective ball. All good balls weigh the same and all defective balls weigh the same, but good balls weigh less than the defective ones, and given a balance, separate the defective balls from the good ones.

My naive attempt at a solution is to just place the first ball in one list, and iterate through the entire list, placing them in their respective lists accordingly. However this is obviously a O(n) solution. I was wondering if there was another more efficient method?

Comment: `just place the first ball in one list` - place it on one side of the scale, and another one on the other. How can you proceed if the weights differ, and how if they are the same?

Comment: well as you iterate through the list eventually you'll find a ball that weighs differently from the first one, and from there you can conclude which list has the good balls / defective balls?

Comment: You will never know which is good and which is defective. But you can separate them...

Comment: I added a clarification to my question, sorry for forgetting about that: good balls weigh less than defective balls

Comment: You simply do a binary search (if you have 10 balls, put 5 on each side of the scale- then take the side which is heavier until you have a 1:1 decision), this is quite a famous question in Microsoft interviews.

Comment: Is it a scale or a balance?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, I don't think this is correct algorithm. There can be 2 good and 3 bad on one side and same on other side. Wheights will be the same and what to do?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri if you have 3 balls, you take 2 each and see whether they are balanced. If they are, the third one is the bad one. If not, you already have the answer. Guess his question is ambiguous, there is *at least one* good ball- and one ball that's defective.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, I know that for one bad ball. What to do when you put 5 balls on one side and 5 balls on another and weignts are same? The tri k is that there can be several bad balls.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri You just know that both sets will have the same number of defective balls (given that you can't compose a defective ball with n good ones). With that knowledge, you can do the binary search for both subsets again. In the worst case you measured all of the ones in a subset with each other and they all weigh the same = you don't know whether they are good balls or not. Given the constraint that at least one needs to be good and at least one bad, this edge case should never occur.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut The number of defective balls is unknown, but there is at least 1

Comment: @yzil cool thanks for the clarification. When the single bad ball constraint is gone, it can't be solvable in sublinear time anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find a solution that's better than O(n) weighings in the worst case. There are 2^n possible outcomes (2^n ways to assign "good" or "bad" to each ball). Each weighing has three possible outcomes, so `m` weighings can differentiate between `3^m` possible outcomes.

Therefore, to differentiate between all the 2^n possible outcomes, you need at least log3(2^n) weighings, which is equal to n*log3(2) = O(n).

So the trivial solution (take one ball and weigh it against each of the others) is the best one asymptotically in the worst case.

Note: This proof is based on the same idea as the proof that comparison sort can't be asymptotically better than O(n*logn).

Comment: So much for the worst case. If the numbers of non-defective and defective balls are very different, you can do better (and there are much less such assignments than "of the same magnitude").

Comment: Good analysis, but log3(2) is about 0.63, which is quite a bit less than 1 (the coefficient of n in the OP's strategy).  I think it's still interesting to see if there is some general O(n) strategy that has a better coefficient than 1.